# Ignore a filed in edit view asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, edit

I have a property in mu model in which I don't want the user to access its value during edit action.
If I don't include it in edit view, it gets a null value. If I include it as a hidden value, user can see it's value through "View Source Code" option in browser.

Any hints?
here is my ProfileController code for Editing Actions

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        Profile profile = null;
        if (_db.Profiles.Count() > 0)
            profile = _db.Profiles.Single(p => p.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        if (null == profile)
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        else
            return View(profile);
    }
    //
    // POST: /Profile/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit( Profile newProfile)
    {
        try
        {
            TryUpdateModel(newProfile);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Entry(newProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                if (newProfile.Confirmed)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
            }
            else
                return View(newProfile);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you just assign that value in your [post]?

Comment: Here is My Scenario: When a user register in the site , i send a 4 digit verification number to his cell phone.i included this verification number to user's profile model. when user wants to edit his profile, I have to hide this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one solution. during registration, when a new record is created in DB, create a new a field for GUID() for that user.

```
new Guid()
```

Then, whenever user wants to edit his/her profile you will have that guid as one of the URL parameters. When pulling the data from the database simply get the record matching that GUID.

```
var record = repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == 'guid from url');
```

record => will hold your users data.

This way you're not showing any verification numbers in any way.

Comment: thanks buddy. But here is my Model. I'm using mvc 3 default AccountController. and i have a Model "Profile" which has fields like "UserName, FirsName, LastName, Cell Phone, City, ..., Verification Number". in edit i use "UserName" to load the data from dbContext and it'll include all fields

Comment: well, in that case "username" has to be unique (no two same usersnames will ever exists). then in your [get] action set verification number = null. and in your [post], you will know which record to update based on the username.

Comment: thanks man. According to Ameen I have to use a new Dbcontext to load original data and update just certain fields.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are editing an existing entry from the database. So you can:

- Load the existing data from the database using the unique identifier of the object
- Overwrite only the set of values that you like to persist from the model you obtained from the POST
- Flush the changes to the database

This way, you don't have to include the confirmation number in your page.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework and Code First model. I'm a newbie and I don't know how exactly "Load the existing data from the database using the unique identifier of the object" . Could you explain how to obtain a unique identifier of the object?

Comment: So, I'm assuming you have a DatabaseContext on hand and a primary key id for the object in question. So you can do something like `databaseContext.SetOfObjectsOfInterest.Find(uniqueId)` to load the item from the database. Then you use the one you got from the POST (in your controller method) and overwrite only the values that you care about on top of the object you got from the database and then save via `databaseContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: thanks. When i send the model in HttpGet method , and user edits fileds and hits save button, the model will return to HttpPost method.ok so far? does new changes to model taken effect or not yet and i can get the original model from context and replace the new values for certain fields?

Comment: Correct. When you get the changes back in HttpPost, they have not been sent to the database yet, so you can use the id of the element, grab the unchanged object from the database, and override the values with the model you get in your HttpPost method. Make sure you use a new DatabaseContext for grabbing the existing item you it should work.